# Can't change/remove a column in a list of dataframes using lapply and dplyr select?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, data-manipulation

I have a list of data frames L:

```
vec1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
val <- c(11, 5443, 552, 9)
vec2 <- c("r", "p", "h", "y") 
val <- c(5, 9, 47, 23)
```

Creating dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(vec1, val, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(vec2, val, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

L <- list(df1, df2)
```

Now I want to delete the val column for example:

```
P <- lapply(L, function (y) {y$val <- NULL})
```

Output:

```
P <- lapply(L, function (y) {y$val <- NULL})
> P
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL
```

Running manually:

```
L[[1]]$val <- NULL
L
[[1]]
  vec1
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    d

[[2]]
  vec2 val
1    r   5
2    p   9
3    h  47
4    y  23
```

For some reason I can't do this but doing it manually it works, please advise.

P.S
I get the list (I am not creating it), and can't access the val because R doesn't know what is it.

```
Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : 
  object 'val' not found
```

When using dplyr select, it can't find the val column:

```
library(dplyr)
P <- lapply(L, function (y) {select(y, -val)})
```

Comment: I think you forgot to `return(y)` after modifying it. and the `dplyr` one works for me.

Comment: @mt1022 It returns an error with dplyr, see my P.S section please.

Comment: Just try to use this as a function `lapply(L, function (y) {y$val <- NULL; y})`

Comment: @AntoniosK will do now and report, what about the dplyr issue? What is wrong here?

Comment: Please make sure that dataframes in `L` still have the `val` column before you run  `P <- lapply(L, function (y) {select(y, -val)})`.

Comment: I think @mt1022 is right in both his comments. I did nothing more than providing the function based on what he said. Whatever you try just make sure you re-build your dataset every time, as you might be changing something after every attempt. :-)

Comment: @mt1022 sure they have, otherwise it will be ridiculous to run it and take your time.

Comment: @AntoniosK please be so kind and explain your comment, what is wrong with my dplyr select statement within lapply? If I will do a for loop and set L[[i]]$val <- NULL what am I missing here?

Comment: Ok, for now lapply(L, function (y) {y$val <- NULL; y}) worked. Can you guys please help me with the select? What is wrong there? @AntoniosK

Comment: You're running your `dplyr` process after you've removed the `val` column. Try to re-build your dataset and then use your `dplyr` process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both commands work for me:

```
library(dplyr)

vec1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
val <- c(11, 5443, 552, 9)
vec2 <- c("r", "p", "h", "y") 
val <- c(5, 9, 47, 23)

df1 <- data.frame(vec1, val, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(vec2, val, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

L <- list(df1, df2)

L

# [[1]]
#   vec1 val
# 1    a   5
# 2    b   9
# 3    c  47
# 4    d  23
# 
# [[2]]
#   vec2 val
# 1    r   5
# 2    p   9
# 3    h  47
# 4    y  23

lapply(L, function (y) {y$val <- NULL; y})

# [[1]]
# vec1
# 1    a
# 2    b
# 3    c
# 4    d
# 
# [[2]]
# vec2
# 1    r
# 2    p
# 3    h
# 4    y

lapply(L, function (y) {select(y, -val)})

# [[1]]
# vec1
# 1    a
# 2    b
# 3    c
# 4    d
# 
# [[2]]
# vec2
# 1    r
# 2    p
# 3    h
# 4    y
```

Comment: I will base my solution using your code template, maybe somewhere it overwrites the val column and I am running full gas on neutral.

Comment: Thanks a lot Antonio, you help me a lot in all my questions here, many thanks!